# Rails: print UTC time by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I have a non-ActiveRecord server which is sending data to another service. That server expects to receive instructions including UTC in the format: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L"`. I already have an time_format.rb initializer that overrides `Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]` Is there a way I can configure my server so that `Time.now.to_s` will by default print UTC time, without me having to specify `Time.now.utc` every time I call it? I'm using ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.

I tried adding `config.time_zone = 'London'` to `config/application.rb` but that did not work.

Comment: How about defining a new method called time_now which calls Time.now.utc?

Comment: You can achieve this by overriding now method in Time class.

Comment: How about config.time_zone = 'UTC'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think ActiveRecord should have anything to do with it, but maybe I'm misunderstanding. Like Sergio said, set your applications timezone to UTC.

Here's my Rails app.  My computer is in PST.  My Rails app is set to UTC.

```
 > Time.now
 => 2014-01-22 21:52:38 -0800
 > Time.zone.name
 => "UTC"
 > Time.zone.now
 => Thu, 23 Jan 2014 05:52:43 UTC +00:00
 > Time.now.utc
 => 2014-01-23 05:52:45 UTC
```

I would strongly advise not overriding Time.now.  That can only lead to the dark side.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to explicitly specify Time.utc, but I couldn't find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

A general purpose solution that works for any Ruby application:

```
module TimeClassExtensions
  def now
    super.utc
  end
end

Time.singleton_class.prepend(TimeClassExtensions)
```